# Clicking and selecting words under a translucent window in X

Tags: c, window, xlib, translucency

Opening a transparent or even translucent window is not rare in Linux desktop nowadays, and it's also very easy to implement. For example, you can draw a translucent window by creating a 32-bit depth visual in Xlib.

But, the picture (snapshoted from my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) bellow confuses me for quite a long time. If it is a window (created by [`XCreateWindow()` or `XCreateSimpleWindow()`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XCreateWindow.html) in Xlib), it will get input focus and start receiving events such as [`Pointer events`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/keyboard-pointer/keyboard-pointer.html).

[image]

- Is that notification window from [Notify OSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD) a window essentially from Xlib perspective?
- If so, how to implement a translucent window that I can click something through it? (Xlib is preferred.)
- Any helps, clues, and suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to know the reason to the down vote... Maybe "I don't like X"?

Comment: Haven't checked source, but theoretically it can be part of compositor and not a "real" window. As a last step of compositing resulting image is transferred to overlay window (it's on top of all windows and doesn't receive input) so in addition to other window sources you can draw anything else, not belonging to any window content. Easy way to check is to add SubstructureNotify listener to root window and listen for new windows (filter by similar size)

Comment: @AndreySidorov Thanks. No `SubstructureNotify` is received in testing followed by your suggestions. I tried to check source and the details of the visual layer that posted on [the website](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=NotificationManager-Design-2.svg), and I found that Notify OSD will interact with **specified** (compositing) window manager such as metacity, kwin, and compiz. So, is there any lower-level method (such as talking to X server directly) to implement this in order to be supported in all desktop environments?

Comment: @AndreySidorov I've just solved this problem by searching overlay window. Thanks for your hints.